# Comparing two json objects and delete null values from the second json object

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to compare 2 objects and merge them with patch json data. Comparing payload and patch and remove fields from payload if the values are null in patch object.

**Input:**

```
{
 "firstname":"John",
 "lastname":"Sam",
 "city": "San Jose",
 "path": "additional",
 "location-1": {
   "address": "USA",
   "pin": null
  },
  "location-2": {
   "address": null,
   "place": "abc",
   "pin": null
  }
}
```

**Dataweave Code:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects

var patch = {
    lastname:"Courtney",
    age:"18",
    path: "",
    company: "MR",
    firstname: null,
    city: null,
  "location-1": {
    "address": "USA",
    "pin": null
    }
  }
---
(payload mergeWith ((patch)) filterObject ($ != null ))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{  
  "lastname": "Courtney",
  "age": "18",
  "path": "",
  "company": "MR",
  "location-1": {
    "address": "USA"
   },
   "location-2": {
    "address": null,
    "place": "abc",
    "pin": null
  }
}
```

but I am unable to remove null value from location-1 object in the output.

Comment: Please.add.the actual output and indicate which value is the one you want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the request then you can use a combination of filterObject() to remove the elements that need removed and mapObject() to apply the filtering recursively to child objects. The recursive function `removeMergedNull()` implements this logic.

I codified the condition for keep an element used for filterObject() in the function `shouldRemove()`.

Then I just apply it to the result of your script.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects

var patch = {
    lastname:"Courtney",
    age:"18",
    path: "",
    company: "MR",
    firstname: null,
    city: null,
  "location-1": {
    "address": "USA",
    "pin": null
    }
  }

fun shouldRemove(x,key, p)=(p == null) or !(keysOf(p) contains (key) as String) and !(p[key as String] == null)        

fun removeMergedNull(o, p)=
    o 
        filterObject ((value, key, index) -> value  match {
                case x is String -> shouldRemove(x, key, p)
                case x is Null -> shouldRemove(x, key, p)         
                else -> true
        })
        mapObject ((value, key, index) -> value  match {
            case child is Object -> (key): removeMergedNull(child,  p[key as String])
            else -> (key):value
    }) 
---
removeMergedNull((payload mergeWith ((patch)) filterObject ($ != null )), patch)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "location-2": {
    "address": null,
    "place": "abc",
    "pin": null
  },
  "lastname": "Courtney",
  "age": "18",
  "path": "",
  "company": "MR",
  "location-1": {
    "address": "USA"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aled. Its the same output I wanted.

Comment: Hi @aled, there is one more addition in patch. If we have array of object in the child, how to add in the function for array. I have added in patch and also corrected the output. Thanks!

Comment: You are changing the question. Since the answer was ok for the original question and the script seems to be creating the modified expected output without issues, I recommend to accept/upvote the answer. Have you tried the solution with the modified patch variable? If you want to clarify more details about the modified transformation then post a new question with the changed input. Please clarify how the new array is supposed to be processed.

Comment: The previous one worked absolutely fine.  But I missed to add another child with array object in patch. So, I have corrected the patch and expected output accordingly.

Comment: What I meant is that I tested my script with your modified patch variable and it gives the modified expected output. Is there anything else that you are asking for?

Comment: Remove fields from payload if the values are null in patch object. In location-3, address and pin are null and should be removed as the values are null and not present in payload and location-3 is inside array[{}]

Comment: I don't understand. Your updated expected output in the question contains both address and pin inside the one item in the location-3 array. I strongly recommend to rollback the question to how it was originally and create a new question for the modified scenario. Modifying questions should be reserved only for clarifications. Converting the question into a new scenario or issue is not a good practice.

Comment: I have rollbacked the previous question and created a new one. Thanks @aled.